# PHP MySQL PDO array bind not returning any results

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a function to search a database for a given search term using PDO. I've got the below which should be binding the contents of the $searchArray array to the statement, but when I run it the printed result is an empty array.

Can anyone advise where I'm going wrong?

```php
function searchReleases($searchTerm){
    global $pdo;
    
    if($searchTerm != "" && !empty($searchTerm)){
        $searchArray = explode(" ", $searchTerm);
        
        $queryArgs = "";
        $loopIndex = 0;
        foreach($searchArray as $term){
            if($loopIndex == 0){
                $queryArgs = $queryArgs . "WHERE index_value LIKE ? ";
            }else{
                $queryArgs = $queryArgs . "AND index_value LIKE ? ";
            }
            $loopIndex += 1;
            
            $term = "%" . $term . "%";
        }
        
        try{
            $query = "SELECT index_releaseId, index_value, COUNT(1) as count FROM releases_index
                        $queryArgs
                        GROUP BY index_releaseId
                        ORDER BY count DESC
                        LIMIT 1,25";
            $selectQuery = $pdo->prepare($query);
            $selectQuery->execute($searchArray);
            $selectResult = $selectQuery->fetchAll();

            $countRow = count($selectResult);
            
            print_r($selectResult);
        }catch(Exception $e){
            echo($e);
        }
        
    }    
}
```

Comment: This won't work: `$term = "%" . $term . "%"` because `$term` is not part of `$searchArray`, it is a separate variable.

Comment: Makes sense - I guess I'd just need to create a second array or is there a better way of doing that?

Comment: A second array would work.

Comment: Nice. You're welcome.